# Authentication error when running deploy:check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app using Capistrano. I followed the tutorial [How to Deploy a Rails 4 App with Git and Capistrano](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano). However, when I run `cap production deploy:check`, it gives me this error:

```
INFO[349a4b8d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/app_name/ on xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG[349a4b8d] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/app_name/
INFO[cd49f0ac] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/app_name/ on example.com
DEBUG[cd49f0ac] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/app_name/
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xx.xxx.xxx: Authentication failed for user @xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

My first thought was that I did need to use sudo, but mkdir shouldn't need sudo in /tmp/. My second thought was that it needs a password for ssh, but I use public keys to ssh between my development computer and the server. Any ideas?

Here is my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'app_name'

set :repo_url, 'git@example.com:remote/app_name.git'
set :scm, :git

set :user, 'deploy'
set :use_sudo, false

set :stage, :production

set :rails_env, 'production'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :keep_releases, 5

set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

set :pty, true

server 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', roles: [:app, :web, :db], primary: true

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.1.0, Rails 4.1.4, and Capistrano 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few things wrong with my setup. First, I forgot to fill in any information in `config/deploy/production.rb`. In this same file, I also added the line `set :password, ask('Server password:', nil)`.

Second, the reason why I had this error is because of permission issues. Apparently this user didn't have permission to modify `/var/www`. To change that, I simply entered `sudo chown deploy:deployers /var/www`. Also, I needed to include login credentials for GitHub on the server.